# Electron: get full path of uploaded file

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm buildind now GUI using Electron. (like PhoneGap for desktop apps)

Is there a way to enable full path for file checked in `<input type="file">`?
Insted of `C:\fakepath\dataset.zip` now.  (the directory name isn't "fakepath", but that is the value of `document.getElementById("myFile").value`)

Or, is there other way to select a file?

Comment: `C:\fakepath\dataset.zip` is a full path. What do you mean?

Comment: No, the directory name isn't `fakepath`, but that exactly what I get from `document.getElementById("myFile").value`.

Comment: You can't get input files like this.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos -- Not in end-user browsers, but you can do this in runtime environments with elevated privileges, such as Electron. Also, `c:\fakepath\<filename>` is not a full path, it's a well known [faked path](https://davidwalsh.name/fakepath), which is there for legacy reasons.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Electron adds a [`path`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/v1.2.8/docs/api/file-object.md) property to [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) objects, so you can get the real path from the input element using:

```
document.getElementById("myFile").files[0].path
```

Comment: `Property 'path' does not exist on type 'File'. ts(2339)`

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to do what you are trying for security reasons, according this answer [How to get full path of selected file on change of <input type=‘file’> using javascript, jquery-ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav/15201258#15201258).

However you could do a work around like I did in an electron project I worked on.

1. Create a HTML button
2. Then in the **renderer process** create an event listener to the button you created before.

   ```
   const ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
   const buttonCreated = document.getElementById('button-created-id');

   buttonCreated.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
       ipc.send('open-file-dialog-for-file')
   });
   ```
3. Then in the **main process** you use the `showOpenDialog` to choose a file and then send the `full path` back to the renderer process.

   ```
   ipc.on('open-file-dialog-for-file', function (event) {
    if(os.platform() === 'linux' || os.platform() === 'win32'){
       dialog.showOpenDialog({
           properties: ['openFile']
       }, function (files) {
          if (files) event.sender.send('selected-file', files[0]);
       });
   } else {
       dialog.showOpenDialog({
           properties: ['openFile', 'openDirectory']
       }, function (files) {
           if (files) event.sender.send('selected-file', files[0]);
       });
   }});
   ```
4. Then in the **renderer process** you get the `full path`.

   ```
   ipc.on('selected-file', function (event, path) {
       console.log('Full path: ', path);
   });
   ```

Thus you can have a similar behaviour than the input type file and get the full path.

Comment: *"It is not possible to do what you are trying for security reasons"* -- This is true for end-user browsers, but not Electron. I believe you can simply use `input.files[0].path`, which is also described in the [currently accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38549837/2788872).

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>

    const electron = require('electron');
    const { ipcRenderer } = electron;
    const ko = require('knockout')
    const fs = require('fs');
    const request = require('request-promise');

    // replace with your own paths
    var zipFilePath = 'C:/Users/malco/AppData/Roaming/Wimpsdata/Wimpsdata.zip';
    var uploadUri = 'http://localhost:59887/api/Collector/Upload'

    var request = require('request');
    request.post({
        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/zip' },
        url: uploadUri,
        body: fs.createReadStream(zipFilePath)
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        console.log(body);
        location.href = 'ScanResults.html';
    });
</script>
```

ASP .NET WebAPI Conontroller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using Wimps.Services.Business;

namespace Wimps.Services.Controllers
{
    public class CollectorController : ApiController
    {

        public async Task<bool> Upload()
        {
            try
            {
                var fileuploadPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileUploadLocation"];

                var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(fileuploadPath);
                var content = new StreamContent(HttpContext.Current.Request.GetBufferlessInputStream(true));
                foreach (var header in Request.Content.Headers)
                {
                    content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(header.Key, header.Value);
                }

                Byte[] byteArray = await content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

                string newFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                string newFilePath = fileuploadPath + "\\" + newFileName + ".zip";
                if (File.Exists(newFilePath))
                {
                    File.Delete(newFilePath);
                }

                File.WriteAllBytes(newFilePath, byteArray);

                string unzipTo = fileuploadPath + "\\" + newFileName;
                Directory.CreateDirectory(unzipTo);

                DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(unzipTo);
                foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
                {
                    file.Delete();
                }

                ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(newFilePath, unzipTo);



                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // handle exception here
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Need to add key to web config for file upload

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
... other keys here
    <add key="FileUploadLocation" value="C:\Temp\Uploads" />
  </appSettings>
```

rest of app config
...
...

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer works great for the original question, but the answer from @Piero-Divasto works a lot better for my purposes.

What I needed was the pathname of a **directory** which may be rather large. Using the accepted answer, this can block the main process for several seconds while it processes the directory contents. Using `dialog.showOpenDialog(...)` gets me a near-instant response. The only difference is that `dialog.showOpenDialog` doesn't take a callback function anymore, and instead returns a promise:

```js
ipcMain.on("open-file-dialog-for-dir", async event => {
  const dir = await dialog.showOpenDialog({ properties: ["openDirectory"] });
  if (dir) {
    event.sender.send("selected-dir", dir.filePaths[0]);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>const electron = require('electron');</script>
<button id="myFile" onclick="this.value=electron.remote.dialog.showOpenDialog()[0]">UpdateFile</button>
```

Now, the `document.getElementById("myFile").value` would contain the full path of the chosen file.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by Vadim Macagon:

```
let { path } = document.getElementById("myFile").files[0]
```

Since there is no included interface for this for TypeScript as of this answer, to use this you have to cast the File to another type

```
let { path } = document.getElementById("myFile").files[0] as any
```

or, if you would rather not use `any`

```
interface ElectronFile extends File {
    path: string;
}

let { path } = document.getElementById("myFile").files[0] as ElectronFile
```